# Gallery with Album Covers

Tags: views, media

I currently have two node types: Album (CCK), and Image (image module, using Image FUpload module).
A user creates an album, simply a title. When they create Image(s), the album is node-referenced.

I have a view of Albums, and I would like to pick one Image from each album to show as a cover photo. I cannot just add a CCK field to the Album for this; the image needs to appear in the view of album images, and every image can be voted and commented on, as well as have their own references (tags).

I tried a few relationships in the View, nothing seemed to pull the image for an album. Is this possible using the Image module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally decided to add a 'Cover' cck field to the Album type. I could not find a way in Views to correctly relate an Album to a View of photos for this purpose using Relationships.

Comment: With Flag you have a possible solution for that. Just flag a particular item,add a relationship using the flag. List it :-)